# Redirect standard output OCaml

Tags: ocaml, redirectstandardoutput

How can you redirect the standard output in OCaml ?
I tried `Format.set_formatter_out_channel` but it doesn't seem to work. When I use printf afterwards, the text is still printed on the screen, and the file I created remains empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your experiment failed is that Printf.printf doesn't use the output channel of the Format module. The Format module is for pretty-printing, a fairly elaborate task. The Printf.printf function writes formatted data to the standard output (a C-style printf).

Do you really want to redirect standard output, or do you just want to write to a specific channel? To write to a channel `oc` you can just use

```
Printf.fprintf oc ...
```

rather than

```
Printf.printf ...
```

Doing redirection is a different thing. You can do it with `Unix.dup2`. Here's an example session that shows how to do it:

```
$ cat redirected
cat: redirected: No such file or directory

$ cat redir.ml
let main () =
    let newstdout = open_out "redirected" in
    Unix.dup2 (Unix.descr_of_out_channel newstdout) Unix.stdout;
    Printf.printf "line of text\n";
    Printf.printf "second line of text\n"

let () = main ()

$ ocamlopt -o redir unix.cmxa redir.ml
$ ./redir

$ cat redirected
line of text
second line of text
```

Since this is changing low-level file descriptors behind the back of the OCaml I/O system, I'd be a little careful. As a quick hack it's fantastic--I've done it many times.

**Update**

Here's a version of the above code that redirects standard output temporarily, then puts it back where it was before.

```
$ cat redirected
cat: redirected: No such file or directory
$
$ cat redir.ml
let main () =
    let oldstdout = Unix.dup Unix.stdout in
    let newstdout = open_out "redirected" in
    Unix.dup2 (Unix.descr_of_out_channel newstdout) Unix.stdout;
    Printf.printf "line of text\n";
    Printf.printf "second line of text\n";
    flush stdout;
    Unix.dup2 oldstdout Unix.stdout;
    Printf.printf "third line of text\n";
    Printf.printf "fourth line of text\n"

let () = main ()
$
$ ocamlopt -o redir unix.cmxa redir.ml
$ ./redir
third line of text
fourth line of text
$
$ cat redirected
line of text
second line of text
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be able to switch from standard output to a file without having to change all printfs to fprintfs. Lazy I guess (when I could just find and replace -- yet I do a hell lot of printfs and having to give every function the output channel in parameter…).

Comment: @Sheeft change `Printf.printf` to `Format.printf` instead and enjoy the new superpowers :-)

Comment: You can use actual redirection if you want to. I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get back to stdout a while later? E.g. if I only want to temporarily redirect the output of one function and then resume normal operations.

Comment: It's not difficult with Unix `dup` to do anything along these lines. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This answer is good, but the updated code leaks both `newstdout` and `oldstdout`.  Run this code in a loop 10k times and it will exhaust all file descriptors.  They need to be closed.